# cpan connection failed permission denied

Tags: perl, cpan

I installed and configured CPAN to use http mirrors and I could install about 10 packages with no problem.

Now I was trying to install `Text::CSV` and I get

```
Connecting to cpan.muzzy.it|95.110.202.104|:80... failed: Permission denied.
```

on all the mirrors that I tried.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Permission denied is usually OS/Filesystem related. You'd get 'connection refused' or HTTP error if it was the connection. 
Can I take a guess and suggest you ran CPAN as root before, and as a nonpriv user now?

Comment: permission denied sounds like permissions on the server you are installing on.  Check that the user you are running as has permissions on paths in @INC like ``/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl``  See the output from ``perl -V`` if you are unsure what these are

Comment: sorry I solved.. as a stupid I enabled a intrusion prevention policy on the server and forgot it.. :/ sorry about that